# How to create own database connection for bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

For a long time of googling I still looking for ideal solution, how to create a second DB connection for a bundle. My system consist of many bundles, but for one of them I need connection not only to original DB, but to another one as well (so 2 connections at once).

I tried it this way in boot() method of my bundle:

```
$connectionFactory = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory');
$connection = $connectionFactory->createConnection(array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'my_user',
    'password' => 'my_pass',
    'host' => '',
    'dbname' => 'my_dbname',
));
$this->container->set('doctrine.dbal.new_connection', $connection);
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('new');
```

But it thrown an error:
**Doctrine EntityManager named "new" does not exist.**

And if I try to add second connection to my config.yml and I call it with

```
$this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('second_connection')
```

It throw the same error.

**EDIT:**
Error was eliminated. It was caused by bad settings of "mappings" parameter in doctrine.dbal.connections.

Now I want create connection to database which is handled by bundle. And app/config/config.yml or other config doesn`t know about this connection. 
Simply stated, when user open page of new bundle handled own connection and entity manager, it will create new connection automaticaly and you can acces to 2 or more databases. Becouse first is original from app/config/config.yml and second is bundle connection.

I tried predefine 2 database connection within app/config/config.yml in doctrin.dbal and entity manager in doctrine.orm. That works fine, but it`s inconvinient for me as i wrote above.

Exixts another sensible solution, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You would configure it in your app/config/parameters.ini file, a la http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: You thought in parameters.ini? I think, it doesn`t matter If I insert db data into parameter or directly to config.yml. And I dont wont second connection to be static. It has to be dynamic and created in code "on fly"

Comment: Er, yes, parameters.ini is what I meant. No idea how to do it dynamically I'm afraid.